# Forgot which email I used, can't login

Tags: support, user-accounts, email

I forgot what email I used for my other ploxtic id: how do you find out what my email was?

The account is user:2078229.

Comment: AFAIK, only moderators are able to see user's email addresses. you should check received mail history on all your email accounts?

Comment: how do i find a moderator?  better yet someone with access to the passwords cause i'd know the pw

Comment: How are you able to login-in to the Meta? IMO use the same email id which you have used in Meta here. Because your both accounts are associated.

Comment: Here's the [list of moderators](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) on StackOverflow.

Comment: So you want access to *your* account about which, the only thing *you* do know is the account number (public information). Isn't this a little suspicious ?

Comment: If going to the mods doesn't work, you could elevate to e-mailing `team@stackoverflow.com` (though the mods would probably tell you that themselves). There's nothing we regular community members can do to help you here, though.

Comment: Sure thing. The email account that you used was `nicetryphisher@notgonnahappen.com`.

Comment: @JackManey Hey, that's my email!

Comment: @GeorgeWBush - Well, at least I didn't mention that the password was `12345`...

Comment: hi, i also forgot my user email address for stackover flow: how i get it back my user is: user:2545154

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately we can't reveal what email you used for privacy reasons. If you lost access to your account, go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery and try out a few email addresses.

If all else fails, use the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page to reach us (Stack Exchange support) privately. We still won't be able to just reveal what email you used, but we have a few other things at our disposal then.

That said, [hims056 is right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170150/forgot-which-email-i-used-cant-login#comment503046_170150) - you can sign into your Stack Overflow account the same way you just signed in here on Meta.