# How to view the e-mail address used to register on an Android device?

Tags: support, android-app

On an Android device, from the Stack Exchange app, how do I view the e-mail address I used to register on Stack Exchange?

Comment: Log out and Log in again - your device should store the email address being used and have you confirm.

Comment: @Sha Doesn't seem do it - just checked.

Comment: Wait, are you going to hijack your roommate's Andoid phone and try to view the email? ;)

Comment: So yet again, looks like this is just not possible via the app itself and actually neither on the site. It depends on what OpenID provider you're using.

Comment: OK, great, so now I've logged out from Menu Icon -> Settings -> Log Out, and when I try to log in again the app doesn't seem to suggest the right username (just a few cached usernames which were recorded by the Samsung Keyboard software show up). So now, all I know is that the username was... don't know that either. What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe this is possible to do it from the app (I wasn't able to find it), so you have to open the site. Go to [My Logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current).

Here you can see the logins with the providers you used - if you remember the provider, that's not a problem :)

> [image]

Comment: Just tell me: is "I'm afraid" more appropriate there?

Comment: You mean instead of "I fear"?

Comment: @James Yes, sure :)

Comment: (IMO) In this specific scenario "I fear" has *some* doubt, as in  "I don't believe this is possible". Whereas "I'm afraid" is more certain, as in "This is not possible". If "I'm afraid" was taken with uncertainty, then it would be bad usage because it literally means you are scared something might not be possible. Whereas (this scenario) "I fear" has a less serious level of concern for someone/something. So as you weren't 100% sure, but *believed* it to be so you used the better one (again this is IMO, and I'm from north England - If you heard me speak you'd probs ignore my English advice :P)

Comment: OK, the user has logged out. I only know that the username that we need to change is "user100380", and before changing that I need to retrieve a recovered password. How should I proceed?

Comment: @John You can't do anything in this case.

Comment: Not even from a web browser. I wish a password reset be sent to the e-mail address that user100380 used to register. And if I cannot know which e-mail address that is than I will try all of them. Is this possible at least? All this trouble because registration was carried out from the Stack Exchange android app instead of from a PC.

Comment: @John Seriously, is your roommate absolutely incapable to do it themselves? You're obviously hacking into their account.

Comment: Well, if I can figure it out (with your help of course) than that would be great because that way the problem can be solved.

Comment: @John Why again, your roommate can't do it themselves?

Comment: A little search brought up [Forgot which email I used, can't login](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170150/forgot-which-email-i-used-cant-login). I assume you or your roommate are able to proceed from there.

Comment: @JohnHigginstyne You were logged in to your account to post here, now suddenly you lost your password, have no access, don't know the email address, and need more info? I agree with nicael, this sounds fishy (sorry if it's not, but it stinks). "*I wish a password reset be sent to the e-mail address that user100380 used to register.*" who is this user? Seems to not be any of your accounts...