# How can I get back my account in a SE site?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, email

First of all, I'd like to make it clear that I've tried to post it on the Math-meta site, since this question could fit better there, but I'm not allowed because I'm new and don't have enpugh reputation yet.

11 days ago I signed up in Math-SE, with my e- mail. I've been using it,asking and answering questions without any problem; but it seems that I forgot to confirm my e-mail by clicking the link that is given by mail when you sign up. 
So yesterday, when I opened Chrome, I was logged out, and when I tried to log in, the page would say :" We could not find an account with that e-mail".

I don't know what to do to get my account back; since the options for recovery of your account assumes your mail is registered, and mine's not.

thanks!

Comment: related: [Forgot which email I used, can't login](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170150/201151)

Comment: I'm sorry, not related, I know which mail I've used. It just didn't got resitered or something like that. I've already clicked on "contact us" and explained the situation, and so far I didn't get an answer. Thanks anyway...